# How do I get the immediate child items in a List with javascript and SP.Service?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, javascript, document-library

I am making use of an SP.Service to retrieve the items of a particular list (Site Assets). I know the way to retrieve all the items under the list: using a caml query and the function createAllItemsQuery(). However I just need to retrieve the immediate child items.

Here is my actual structure of Site Assets:

```
      SiteAssets
          Folder1
             Folder1.1
             Folder1.2
          Folder2
             Folder2.1
          Etc...
```

So at the moment I am retrieving absolutely all the items bellow SiteAssets, and I wish only to retrieve Folder1, Folder2, which are the immediate child items of the lists.

Following is the code that I am using:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveAllListProperties, "sp.js");

      function retrieveAllListProperties()
      {

        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Site Assets');
        var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();  <-------// The caml query I am using
        allItems = list.getItems(query);
        context.load(allItems, 'Include(DisplayName,Id)'); <-------// Loading the context of the items
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.viewSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
      }

      function viewSuccess() 
      {
        var TextFiled = "";
        var ListEnumerator = allItems.getEnumerator(); <-------// Getting all the items, I just need the immediate child items, not sub-child items
        while (ListEnumerator.moveNext()) 
        {
          var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
          var title = currentItem.get_displayName();
          var id = currentItem.get_id().toString();
          console.log("Title: " + title + " Id: " + id); <-------// I am printing at the moment the name of the child and it's id
        }
      }

      function failed(sender, args) 
      {
        console.log('failed. Message:' + args.get_message());
      }
```

Is it posible to retrieve only the immediate child items? Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be using SP.Services -- just the Javascript Client Object Model:

I did however learn something interesting by looking in to this...

To get the behavior you want, use an empty string as the CamlQuery argument to getItems:

```
allItems = list.getItems("");
```

I was previously under the impression this did the same thing as using `SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery()` as the argument, but it seems the default scope (since the empty string just represents an empty query) is not recursive, while createAllItems is -- which makes sense logically, just not something I had put together before!

Comment: You are amazing! That indeed solved my problem.
Thank you very much!